# How to treat !important when implementing custom bootstrap theme?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-selectors

## My scenario

I've recently written a simple website in Bootstrap 4.1, which is supposed to use a specific shade of purple for all its colouring needs.

My idea was to create a CSS class `.btn-purple`, which overwrites all necessary colour-related attributes, such as `color`, `background-color`, `border-color`, etc.

This worked well for the basic colouring scheme, but as soon as it came to different button states, such as `:hover`, `:focus` and `:active`, I saw that Bootstraps built-in selectors were considred ["more specific"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than my simple class-selector and thus overruled them.

## My "fix"

I temporarily fixed this by applying `!important` to all my custom selectors. This, however, seems to be considered bad design and I am uncertain how to fix this. The page I linked to specifically states the following:

> - **Always** look for a way to use specificity before even considering `!important`.
> - **Only** use `!important` on page-specific CSS that overrides foreign CSS (from external libraries, like Bootstrap or normalize.css).

This seems a little contradictory for me. I am uncertain if in my use-case the usage of `!important` is justified, or if it is still considered a hack.

Further, I want to add that I am using Bootstrap as provided by their CDN. As such, compiling my own flavour is something I would like to avoid.

## My question

What is the prefered way to dealing with `!important` in this situation?

Comment: if bootstrap is not using !important for sure you can be more specific .. by the way did you consider adding the style to all the states (hover,focus, etc) ?

Comment: Adding it to all states is not possible, since for example a button should be outline-only normally, and filled when hovered over. `:active` and `:hover` currently share the same content.

Comment: well, it's possible to add to all states and to control the CSS like you want ... share an example where it's *impossible* for you to do it

Comment: I will need a moment to compile an [mcve] then

Comment: I feel like an idiot right now. I will write down an answer explaining my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to create a minimal example to show my problem, I realized where the source of all my problems came from. The following example is how I created my buttons:

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-purple" href="#">
```

Since I always applied the "primary" style to my buttons, my custom class had trouble overriding the style. The solution was simply to remove `btn-outline-primary` and implement `btn-outline-purple` myself like this:

```
.btn-outline-purple {
    color: #490088;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: #490088;
}

.btn-outline-purple:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-outline-purple:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #490088;
    border-color: #490088;
}

.btn-outline-purple:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(73, 0, 136, 0.5);
}
```

Like this, the behaviour of `.btn-outline-*` will be emulated without any `!important` styles. A new button would then be created as follows:

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-purple" href="#">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try overwriting the variable defaults:

[Theming Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults)

> Every Sass variable in Bootstrap 4 includes the !default flag allowing you to override the variable’s default value in your own Sass
>   without modifying Bootstrap’s source code. Copy and paste variables as
>   needed, modify their values, and remove the !default flag. If a
>   variable has already been assigned, then it won’t be re-assigned by
>   the default values in Bootstrap.
>
> Variable overrides within the same Sass file can come before or after
>   the default variables. However, when overriding across Sass files,
>   your overrides must come before you import Bootstrap’s Sass files.
>
> Here’s an example that changes the background-color and color for the
>    when importing and compiling Bootstrap via npm:

```
// Your variable overrides
$body-bg: #000;
$body-color: #111;

// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

> Repeat as necessary for any variable in Bootstrap, including the
>   global options below.